# regular expression for hexadecimal

Tags: python, regex

I have defined a regular expression of hexadecimal value of length 4 as follows:

```
([0-9A-F]{4})
```

And it works fine and grammatically

```
0000
```

is also a valid hexadecimal number , but I want to discard it from the valid matching and therefore looking forward to hint on how to extend the current regular expression so that

```
0000 is flagged as invalid and filtered out.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [*negative lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?!0000)[0-9A-F]{4}
```

Here `(?!0000)` is a negative lookahead group. It more or less says: "*And do not allow that the next elements are `0000`*" but without *consuming* them.

You can test it on [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/jUl0gz/1).

Comment: How would you modify this to get 0000 as well? For me that could be a valid sequence.

Comment: @EddieC.: you drop the `(?!0000)` part. This will of course only match hexadecimal numbers of length four, for an arbitrary length it is `[0-9A-F]+` (one or more) and `[0-9A-F]*` (zero or more).